# How strong is the force of space expansion?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, cosmology, reference-frames, space-expansion

There are many questions about space expansion, its cause, or its
effects. But I have the feeling we never get straight and simple
answers. I do not expect answers to be simple in general, but I
wondered whether I could use simple reasonning to answer some
questions. Disclaimer: I do not know General Relativity.

One answer I have seen many times is that space expansion is not
strong enough to disrupt most structures of the universe, such as an
atom or a solar system, because there are stronger forces binding
these structures. This argument led me to think that space expansion
acts as a force, but there was no hint as to the nature of that force or
its strength.

So, I tried to evaluate it on my own, which I do below, and my
question is whether my simplistic reasonning is valid, and whether my
terminology is correct *(and to cut short criticism, that led me to
understand that it shows only indirectly as a force)*.

Since an independent body is simply carried away by the Hubble flow, I
first need to consider a simple system that will naturally oppose
it. Short of a non existing anchor to block an object against
the Hubble flow, I thought of a set up that is similar to Arthur
C. Clarke's space elevator, which balances the elevator below a
geosynchronous satellite with a counterweight above the satellite (on
the outerspace side).

Basically I am considering two objects $A$ and $B$ with the same mass
$m$. The two objects are connected with a very long and strong
massless rope of length $2l$, and I call $O$ the middle of the rope (I
recommend ropes made by [General Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Products)).

Since this system is symetrical, I suppose that both masses $A$ and
$B$ are pulled away from $O$ by space expansion, but are stopped by
the rope, the pull on one object being balanced by an opposite pull on
the other. Since everything is happening on the line $(A,B)$, we can
analyze the system in one dimension, using scalars rather than
vectors.

The relative speed due to expansion applied to 2 independent objects at distance $x$ is
defined by $v=H_0x$. Deriving this, we have the acceleration of their
relative expansion induced motion $\gamma=H_0v=H_0^2x$.

Object $A$ would thus move away from $O$ with an acceleration
$\gamma_A=H_0^2l$, but is prevented by the rope where $B$ is balancing
it. Hence $A$ is accelerated in the opposite sense with respect
to the Hubble flow by the pull of the rope. Hence the pull on the rope
is $F_A=mH_0^2x$. It is opposed in $O$ by a pull from B that is equal
and opposite.

This shows several things:

- the force produced by space expansion is
  proportional to the mass of the object it is applied to. It is not
  really a force but an acceleration;
- this force (or acceleration) appears when the object cannot follow
  normally the expanding Hubble flow because it is bound to a
  structure larger than itself;
- this force is centrifugal with respect to the structure, and must
  be balanced by an opposite centripetal force originating from the
  larger structure;
- this force is proportional to the size of the structure (probably
  something like the distance to its center of mass),
- and the proportionality constant is the square of the Hubble
  constant $H_0$, which, given the already very small value of $H_0$,
  is extremely small.

Assuming it is correct, that is the kind of answer I would have liked
to some questions, but did not see.

I could not very well give that myself as an answer because no
question was asked exactly that way, and it would be very presomptuous
anyway, considering that I know nearly nothing of general relativity.

So I am simply asking: is it correct, and is the terminology adequate?

If I am not correct, is there a better treatment of this question that can be understood at about the same level?

Or is it fully correct and should I reorganize my question as a question plus an answer by myself?

Comment: The calculation you're trying to do is done in this answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/70056/4552

Comment: Though I missed your answer in my search, I never doubted that you can
write a better informed answer than I can. But, given your book, I am
surprised you do not understand my intent. I am trying to skip the big
theory, and get an intuition and simple maths for how expansion can
work, independently of what is causing it. Pretty much as gravitation
was described without knowing its causes. The understanding is built
on a (necessarily) gedanken experiment. All I am asking is whether
anything is wrong in this presentation, and possibly what are the
limits of its accuracy. If anyone will tell.