# Why do gravitationally bound regions not feel the expansion of the universe but the rate of expansion of the universe does depend on gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, space-expansion

From Wikipedia,

> The expansion of the universe is the increase in distance between any two given **gravitationally unbound** parts of the observable universe with time,

implying that gravitationally bound regions are not affected. I have heard this statement here on StackExchange, too.

However, from Friedmann's second equation,
$\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} =  -\frac{4 \pi G}{3}\left(\rho+\frac{3p}{c^2}\right) + \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}$, gravity is presumably factored in through the energy density term $ρ$.

Question: why are the influences of gravity and expansion of space asymmetric? Or they are and my logic is simply flawed? If so, how is it flawed?

Comment: You cannot use Friedman’s equation on local scales where the metric is not described by an FRLW universe.

Comment: @gmarocco Could you expand on that just a bit and post that as a separate answer so that I can tick it? For example, is it true that local changes in gravity have no effect on the local rate of expansion of the universe? If the answer is 'yes', that would solve the problem of symmetry and answer my question.

Comment: They are affected, just not by much.  Imagine the expansion of space trying to stretch a spring.

Comment: Sure I’ll do so shortly.

Comment: @m4r35n357 I believe your statement is incorrect; see my answer.

Comment: Gravitationally bound systems are affected, but in tightly bound cases such as a solar system or a galaxy they are affected by far too little to be measurable. The secular trend is proportional to $d/dt(\ddot{a}/a)$.

Comment: duplicate or near duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70047/can-the-hubble-constant-be-measured-locally

Comment: @AndrewSteane I was attempting to paraphrase a statement by Leonard Susskind in his continuing education lecture series on GR, and what I was trying to say corresponds to Ben Crowell's comment.  Your answer is above my pay grade!

Comment: Andrew Steane's answer basically says what I was going to say, so there's not much point in me writing up an answer. I might add that the scale factor is only a well defined concept in an FRW homogeneous and isotropic universe, so we cannot even really talk about a well-defined rate of expansion in the more complicated geometry of our local neighbourhood.

Answer (score 1):

Friedmann equations treated a case where there is uniformly distributed matter and cosmological constant. This is a good approximation on a large enough scale. However, in any given galaxy or solar system you don't have uniformly distributed matter: you have clumps of matter (stars, planets) and near-vacuum in between. So some other solution of the field equation applies.

A study of the Schwarzschild and de Sitter-Schwarzschild solutions gives some good general guidance on what to expect within any given solar system. By employing Birkhoff's theorem one learns that for the case of a single spherical star at the middle of a spherical void inside a spherically symmetric matter distribution, the solution in the void (the region outside the star, and inside the rest) is Schwarzschild (or de Sitter-Schwarzschild) even if the further matter is expanding outwards. So this helps you to see why gravitationally bound systems do not expand, to first approximation, with the cosmic expansion. A planet orbiting such a star will have an orbit whose radius and period does not change with time.

Since in fact there is never perfect spherical symmetry nor perfect vacuum, the precise situation will not be quite like that, but it gives the correct starting-point for further calculation.