# Expansion of the Universe inside mattar

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-constant, matter

When talking about the expansion of the universe we usually refer to the Friedman equations so we assume homogeneous and isotropic solution to Einstein field equation which is true on cosmological scale.

Do we know anything about what happand in regions like solid or starts?
I don't think those assumptions will be valid anymore, so do we still have any idea if there is also an expansion there?

Comment: There is no expansion there. See e.g. [Can the Hubble constant be measured locally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70047/can-the-hubble-constant-be-measured-locally) and the many related links there